# How to remove all text from right after certain characters in excel

Tags: excel, formula

Sorry I'm a noob in excel and need help with this. Say I have the following text in my excel.

1. D:/folder A/ folder B.1/text_01.txt
2. D:/folder A/Folder C/ folder C.1/text_02.msg

I like to remove all the text from the right after the first occurrence "/" counting from the right.

So I would get the followings.

1. D:/folder A/ folder B.1
2. D:/folder A/Folder C/ folder C.1

Answer (score 1):

Use LEFT() with FIND and SUBSTITUTE to find the last `/`

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","")))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a bit of [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), then `InStrRev` was almost tailor made for cases like these:

```
Public Function Remove_After(ByVal what As String, ByVal where As Range) As String
    Remove_After = Left(where, InStrRev(where, what) - 1)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Note, if you want to keep the slash `/` then simply remove the `-1` from the code

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2016+ with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[position()<last()]"))
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

[image]